# Can I merge RAC signals but still get each error individually?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

***Update:***

Instead of:

```
RACSignal * mergedItemsSignals = [RACSignal merge:itemSignalsArray];
```

generate your new signal like this:

```
RACSignal * mergedItemsSignals = [RACSignal merge:[itemSignalsArray.rac_sequence map:^id(RACSignal * signal) {
        return [signal materialize];
    }]];
```

And when you subscribe you expect `RACEvents` which you can distinguish using `[RACEvent eventType]`.

---

With an array of signals I want to be able to process individually each `next` and each `error`. But I'm struggling to find the appropiate operator. So far it seems the proper choice is

`merge`:
*Returns a signal that passes through values from each of the given signals, and sends `completed` when all of them complete. If **any** signal sends an error, the returned signal sends `error` immediately.*

So, it seems that I need something similar. I want to receive all errors, but the unified signal should keep working instead of finishing on the first one.

I tried using 'combineLatest' as well, but this only forwards events once each signal has sent something, and I want to start forwarding as soon as possible for each signal.

Hope it's clear enough, and someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A signal can only error once, so you'll need a way to convert those `error`s into `next`s. Fortunately, `materialize` does just that -- given a signal, it gives you a signal of *events* from that signal. You can then split that into two signals, for the errors, and nexts, -- or just process them in a single block.

So you can take a list of signals, map `materialize`, and then merge the resultant mapped signals.

```
- (RACSignal *)mergeEvents:(NSArray *)signals {
    return [RACSignal merge:[signals.rac_sequence map:^(RACSignal *signal) {
        return [signal materialize];
    }]];
}
```

Comment: This way would allow me to process once all the signals have failed/completed right? Just so I understand, I'd get a next event for everything, be it 'next', 'error' or 'complete' and would have to filter, right? If so, how would I recognize each event? Thanks!

Comment: @andres-ciano You're actually getting a signal of `RACEvent`s, and you can inspect the `eventType` to see what type it is (and then dig into the `error` or `value` as appropriate).

Comment: I didn't know about getting the type of event. Also, just tried your solution and it works awesome! Thanks!